# Android placement of custom XML files

Tags: android

I have a large XML file which is arranged like so:

> `<item><title>...</title><link>...</link></item>`

How can I use `parse(new InputSource());` to point to this XML file if it's stored within my project directory and where do I put the XML file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best answer ignores your `parse(new InputSource())` request. Put it in `res/xml/` and use `getResources().getXml()`. This gives you an `XmlPullParser` on your data. The big advantage here is that your XML is somewhat pre-parsed during the compile step, and so parsing is about ten times faster at runtime than with normal XML parsers.

If it absolutely positively has to use DOM or SAX, put it in `res/raw/`, then use `getResources().openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream`, which you can wrap in an `InputSource`.