# Parsing with XmlPullParser from SDcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, xmlpullparser

what I'm doing wrong?

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/new.xml");
XmlPullParser parser1 = Xml.newPullParser();
parser1.setInput(in, "utf-8");
```

ok.
try parsing each tag of xml code

```
while (parser1.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

Toast.makeText(this, parser1.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
parser1.nextToken();}
```

error :(

Comment: runtime error? compiler error? exception? output not as you expected? Please do not put us into guess game. Put more details

Comment: Runtime error. With data initialization as XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.new) was all ok.

Comment: is your sdcard mount dir ok? is there really new.xml? have you added permission in manifest for accessing external storage?

Comment: Yes, the file exists, the same program successfully writes to disk.    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> or to read something want?

Comment: read the file into a buffer string, parses it. all ok

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079637/xmlpullparser-how-to-attain-res-raw-xml-xmlfilename/6079787#6079787) by hackbod.

Answer (score 1):

So, it works (exception handling is not shown):

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/new.xml");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```